# Filter geojson file to Get last 24 Hours Data

Tags: geojson, mapbox, filter, mapbox-gl

i am using mapbox platform to showing the map in my site.

geojson is having time attribute
Ex: "time":1510301955145
I want to show the map of last 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your geojson data using the [`filter`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#geojson-filter) option:

```
var yourLayer = L.geoJson(yourJson, {filter: yourFilter}).addTo(map);

function yourFilter(feature) {
    // yesterday expressed in milliseconds
    var yesterday = new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    // filter logic
    if (feature.properties.time > yesterday) return true;
}
```

To understand how the `yesterday` variable is calculated:

- `Date()` is the current date and time (today);
- `Date().getTime()` is the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1 1970 and today;
- `(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` is the number of milliseconds in a day;
- `Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` is the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1 1970 and yesterday.

Comment: But it wont work in my case. my page code is like this example : https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/multiple-geometries/

Comment: How can i fit your answer as like that example ? plz help

Comment: Simply use `"filter": [">", "$time", yesterday]` as option when you add the layer.

Comment: at where i have to define/assign yesterday?

Comment: before adding the layer, e.g. in the `map.on("load", function()`.